# WPF get current frame

Tags: wpf, frame

I'm making a WPF application with in the mainpage a Frame and some buttons.
If i press Button1 my frame navigates to Page1,

> Page1 vPage1 = new Page1();
>   Frame.Content = vPage1;

If i press Button2 it should only navigate to Page2 if Page1 is open in the Frame.
How can I check if Page1 is open?

Thx

Comment: why can't you use a boolean variable?

Comment: why don't you use a interface and provide next and previous page. or even you can play around and store variables on Navigation events

Comment: Well its a little more complicated then my question,. I just tryed to ask it simple.

Comment: Just found a way to do it (maby not the right one but it works):
String vTest = Frame.Content.ToString();
IF (vTest == "<Projectname>.Page1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a sample for you.

XAML

```
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Frame x:Name="fram" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"
           Background="Silver"
           Navigated="Frame_Navigated"
           Source="Pages/Page1.xaml" />
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1"
                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button x:Name="btnPrev"
                Click="btnPrev_Click"
                Content="Prev" />
        <Button x:Name="btnNext"
                Click="btnNext_Click"
                Content="Next" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Code.

```
 int pageindex;

        private void btnPrev_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (pageindex <= 1)
            {
                fram.Navigate(new Uri("Pages/Page" + (pageindex + 2) + ".xaml",UriKind.Relative));
                return;
            }
            fram.Navigate(new Uri("Pages/Page" + (pageindex - 1) + ".xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }

        private void btnNext_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (pageindex >= 3)
            {
                fram.Navigate(new Uri("Pages/Page" + (pageindex - 2) + ".xaml", UriKind.Relative));
                return;
            }
            fram.Navigate(new Uri("Pages/Page" + (pageindex + 1) + ".xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }

        private void Frame_Navigated(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            pageindex = Convert.ToInt32(e.Content.GetType().Name.Substring(4));
        }
```